# Comparing Elements at the same Index in two lists

Tags: haskell

My problem is the following:

I have one function that returns a specific list, lets say we have:

`Func = [1,14,12,19,17]`

Now I have another list, lets say:
`List = [14,11,12,13,19]`

I want to find out if the first element of `Func` is equal to the first element of `List`, if the second element of `Func` is equal to the second element of `List`, and so on.

If that is the case, I want to "return" the element. In this example, the correct output of the function I want to create should be 12, because only at the Index 2 the elements in both lists are equal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any specific problems with implementing this?

Comment: Honestly I don't have any idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find l1 l2 = map fst . filter (\(x,y) -> x == y) $ zip l1 l2
```

Or even more concise:

```
find l1 l2 = map fst . filter (uncurry (==)) $ zip l1 l2
```

Comment: Probably I should've been more precise: I want to return ALL the Elements that are equal and have the same Index, not just the first one. Could you modify your answer?

Comment: Think about the intermediate values produced by this answer. Are any of them useful for your clarified problem?

Comment: I was testing the three functions with the input find [1..5] [1..5]. The corresponding output is 1, which is a correct Element, but the Elements 2,3,4 and 5 also match in both lists, so they should be returned too.

Comment: Consider why each of those answers works and what intermediate values are calculated in the process of producing the final output `1`.

Comment: The following modification works: find l1 l2 = map fst $  filter (\(x,y) -> x == y) $ zip l1 l2. My test input was: find [1..8] [1,2,3,3,5,9,7,10] == [1,2,3,5,7]